# finding the format command

Tags: find, format

I need to find where the format command is located its not in my windows stystem. What command would I use to find it. From the command line prompt (not gui)

Comment: closed duplicate: [locating format command](http://superuser.com/questions/201653/locating-format-command-closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would use the dos command 'cd' for change directory.

type:

cd\windows\system32

when you hit enter you will be in the correct directory to use the 'format' command

Comment: i checked widows its not there y nee a prompt that wii find commands when you dont kow where they are,

Comment: what version of windows are you running? it most certainly should be in the \system32\ folder you will find in the \windows\ folder on the hard drive you boot from. if you are running something really old it may be somewhere else. the windows search function works well. open the search, tell it to look in hard drives and choose to search hidden and system folders. it found it in my \windows\system32\... but i knew it would

Answer (score 1):

Generally it should be under `C:\WINDOWS\System32` as `format.com`. If it was moved, for whatever reason, you can search the drive for it like so:

```
cd\
dir /s /b format.com
```

For an even quicker search, check out [Everything](http://voidtools.com/) from voidtools.

Answer (score 0):

Vista and above? 
where format

(should be something like C:\Windows\System32\format.com)

Comment: It's not there I need to find it elsewhere it could be on 1 or 2 of my usb drives, or my seperate hard drive it's not in my windows\sytem32. i need a comand to find it when i dont know where it is.

Comment: dir /s /b format.com